# Python Flask Button to get Unique values

Tags: python, post, flask

I am trying to get a list sets of information :

```
Name:
Date:
Status:
```

It will be displayed in the HTML page so e.g

```
Name: John
Date: 11 January 2018
Status: Pending


Name: Alex
Date: 10 January 2018
Status: Pending
```

There will be a button for each of the above data named 'Confirm'.
How do I go about so that when I click the 'Confirm' button on one of the data above, it will only process and make use of that data? 
e.g if I click the button on Name : Alex, it will only get the info of Alex.

How do I go about doing this in Python Flask?
I can do a POST but how do I capture that the data being sent is from that specific set?
Please give me some suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Identities

Information that is stored on a computer has to be identified through a means somehow. This can be done with an index such as an incrementing index, a GUID, a SHA hash or some other kind of random generator that can create an random id. The random id can then be given a 'purpose' to represent that data.

I'm not sure how you have implemented this in Flask. Whether this is done with 
some kind of SQL driver, a JSON/XML object, or whether this is written in plain text. However, the place to start is how you're storing your data so that you can figure out the best way to use it.

#### Use of Payloads

Payloads are basically where you can give or send all data rather than metadata or identities. This could allow you to identify or change the information before it is stored or sent. However this is normally done to upload/download and change data with an API rather than used to identify data as it would take longer to process.

#### Solution

The best one out of the two would be to use identification. The implementation could be as simple as visiting a link that contains an ID that (REST) API's would typically use (e.g. /statuses/1 or /statuses/321THISISUNIQUE).

You could create a form that contains that id as part of a value such as:

```
<form action='/statuses' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='321THISISUNIQUE'/>
    <input class='confirm' type='submit' value='confirm'/>
</form>
```

Example to get a status using an id

```
@app.route('/statuses/<id>')
def getStatus(id):
    return 'Status for %s' % id
```

Example to use POST with an id ([Refer to Flask - the request object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#the-request-object))

```
@app.route('/statuses', methods=['POST'])
def changeStatus():
    # Technically this should be a PUT request as part of REST
    id = request.args.id
    return 'Change status with id %s' % id
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [flask-sqlalchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/) would make it easy for you. Then you can retreive all data from database, and when user click the button you will call a view function which will take `Name` or you can change to the person `id`.

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Person(db.Model):
    Name = db.Column(db.String)
    Date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    Status = db.Column(db.String)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    persons = Person.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', persons=persons)

@app.route('person-info/<name>')
def person_info(name):
    person = Person.query.filter_by(Name=name).first()
    return render_template('person.html', person=person)

#index.html
{% for person in persons %}
    ...
    <a href="{{ url_for('person_info', name=person.Name)}}">
{% endfor %}

#person.html
{{person.Name}}{{person.Status}}{{person.Date}}
```